# Rails Update method never called

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm facing a problem than I can resolve. 
I try to update an object without success. Rails calls the "edit" method but never the "update" method.

This is my controller :

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

def new
 @job = Job.create(company_id: current_user.recruiter.company.id)
 redirect_to edit_job_url(@job)
end

def edit
 @job = Job.find(params[:id])
 session[:edit_job_id] = @job.id
end

def update
 @job = Job.find(params[:id])
 @job.update_attributes(job_params)

 if @job.save
  redirect_to @job
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end

private
def job_params
 params.require(:job).permit!.merge(company_id:   current_user.recruiter.company.id)
end

end
```

And this is my edit view :

```
<%= form_for @job do |f| %>
  ......
 <p>
  <%= f.submit 'Ajouter' %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

Is there anyone who can advice me ? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This is my routes :

```
mount Bootsy::Engine => '/bootsy', as: 'bootsy'
root 'static_pages#home'
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations', :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
resources :companies
resources :jobs
resources :candidates
resources :addresses
resources :job_languages, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]  
resources :job_skills, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
resources :job_study_types, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :job_certifications, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :candidate_languages, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]  
resources :candidate_experiences, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
resources :candidate_studies, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
resources :candidate_skills, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
resources :candidate_trainings, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Nested forms :

```
<form>
<input type="text" data-model="DataSkill" id="live_data_skill_id" class="live_data_search"/>
<input type="hidden" id="data_skill_id"/>

<select id="data_skill_level">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>    
</select>

Expérience :
<input type="text" id="data_skill_start_year"/>
<input type="text" id="data_skill_end_year"/>

<input type="hidden" id="old_skill_id"/>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="add_data_skill">Enregistrer</a>
```

```
<form>
<select id="data_language_id">
  <option value=""></option>
  <%= DataLanguage.ordered.each do |lang| %>
    <option value="<%= lang.id %>"><%= lang.name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
<select id="data_language_level">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>    
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="old_language_id"/>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="add_data_language" data-url="job_languages">Enregistrer</a>
```

Comment: form_for @job, url: {action: "update"} please try this in the edit file. This will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've already tried this solution and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: have u defined routes for this controller in routes.rb? Can you please show how have you defined routes?

Comment: I added my routes

Comment: form_for(@job, :url => job_path, method: :put) Can you try this.

Comment: Try loading the `edit` view in the browser, then right click somewhere near the form and click `inspect element`. What is the action path for the form?

Comment: can you add your `edit.html.erb`?

Comment: My action path = "/jobs/31"

Comment: Very confusing. It doesn't hit your strong params does it?

Comment: No. It's like the "update" method doesn't exist. When I click on the button, nothing happens. I have no messages in my console.

Comment: Very weird. I'll say it's a little strange how in your `new` action you're creating, then redirecting to `edit` but I don't think that should be causing the problem. My advice would be to put in the `pry` gem and litter your jobs controller with `binding.pry`'s until you find where it hits

Comment: Maybe I found the problem. In my edit.html.erb, there are two nested forms. When I comment them, the "update" method works. So what is wrong with these two nested forms ?